# Debug a react-native application using nuclide

Tags: react-native, nuclide-editor

Is there any good document/video that talks about how to debug a react-native application using Nuclide.

Am a newbie. Its my first time app development and first time with React.

I did create the project using `react-native init`. I don't think i found a BUCK file for me to run and debug my app. I also don't see to get how to view the errors in my JS file. I have to run the simulator to see. I run it using `react-native run-ios`.

I tried `Nuclide->React Native->Start Debugging`. Not sure what this is supposed to do.

Sorry if these questions sound silly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this instruction](https://nuclide.io/docs/platforms/react-native/) you should:

1. From the [command Palette](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/basics/#command-palette) (Cmd-Shift-P) choose "Nuclide React Native: Start Packager" to start the React Native Server.
2. Ensure that you are in the root directory of the React Native project, then run the application from the command-line: "$ react-native run-ios" (or choose other existing simulator, for example react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone4s").
3. After starting the server, you can prime the React Native Debugger for when the application begins running. From the [command Palette](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/basics/#command-palette) (Cmd-Shift-P), launch "Nuclide React Native: Start Debugging".
4. From the Simulator press Cmd-D (Ctrl-D on Linux). This will bring up the debug options for your application. Select "Debug JS Remotely.

...After you enable debugging from the simulated application, Nuclide will attach to that debugging process automatically, since we primed the Debugger above.

Comment: I cannot find Nuclide React Native: Start Debugging in commadn pallete

Comment: also "Nuclide React Native: Start Packager" does not appear to be a thing

Answer (score 0):

Debug JS in Nuclide is now an option in the dev menu added in React Native version 0.52 December 2017 release.
[See This](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.52.0)